# Function that return new Array with prime numbers only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

Hello friends, 
I wanna create function that return new Array with prime numbers only. 
My function should return only prime numbers, but it return not only prime. 
Would you be so kind to tell me how can I improve my function (or make corectly)? 
Thank you in advanced!!

```
function getAllPrimeNumber(array, num) {
    array = new Array();
        for (var i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
            for(var j = 2; j < i; j++){
                if(i % j==0){break; }
                array.push(i);
            }

        }
    return array;
}
console.log(getAllPrimeNumber([], 5)); //[3, 5, 5, 5]
console.log(getAllPrimeNumber([], 9)); //[3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9]
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: It pushed a numbers several times, and not only prime @MattClark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that `i` can't be fully divided by all numbers from 2 up to `i / 2` not including itself (if the number is 2), and only then push `i` into the array:

```js
function getAllPrimeNumber(num) {
  var array = [];
  var isPrime;
  for (var i = 2; i <= num; i++) {    
    for (var j = 2; (isPrime = i === j || i % j !== 0) && j <= i / 2; j++) {}

    isPrime && array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
}
console.log(getAllPrimeNumber(5));
console.log(getAllPrimeNumber(9));
```